# Regex for only hours or hours and minutes

Tags: regex

I am using regex `^(([0-9])|([0-1][0-9])|([2][0-3])):(([0-9])|([0-5][0-9]))$` for time. It is very good regex but when user wants to enter only hours like 8 or 12 without colon and minutes it is not allowing. 
Can any one suggests which regular expressions suits hours only or hours:minutes.

Comment: So which other scenarios should be valid for you? Enter only hours, no  colon, no minutes. Enter only minutes no colon, no hours, etc?? If they only enter a digits with no colons how can you know if its hours or minutes?

Comment: You can use more than one regex for possible input variations instead of building a single huge one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^(([0-9])|([0-1][0-9])|([2][0-3]))(:(([0-9])|([0-5][0-9])))?$
```

made the ":mm" part optional by putting it in `()` and adding a `?` quantifier.

---

An explanation as generated by https://www.regexplained.co.uk/

[image: Regex description]

First group (labeled as "group #4"):

- A single digit (0..9), or
- A '0' or '1', followed by a single digit (00..19), or
- A '2', followed by a 0, 1, 2 or 3 (20..23)

Then an *optional* second group (labeled as "group #8")

- A colon (':'), followed by
- Either a single digit (0..9), or
- A 0..5 followed by a single digit (00..59)

Answer (score 1):

Just make the last part optional, like this:

```
 ^(([0-9])|([0-1][0-9])|([2][0-3]))(:(([0-9])|([0-5][0-9])))?$
```